# C how to read in a single bit from a file

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, fgets

I'm reading in a file in binary in C: `infile=fopen(input, "rb")` and am attempting to read each bit one at a time so if the file contents were:

"hello"

the ascii value of 'h' is `104` so in binary it would be `1101000`.

Is there a fgetbit() method which you can call and assign to a primitive type? EX:

```
int my_bit=fgetbit(infile); //value of my_bit would be 1 for hello example.
```

Comment: I made a simple library to do just this: https://github.com/thedeg123/bitio

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't get more granular than a byte during file I/O, but if you really want to work at the bit level, you can use a bit mask or a bit shift to isolate the bits you want once you have the bytes read out of the file.

For example, to output/examine every single bit in a byte:

```
#include <limits.h> // for CHAR_BIT

...

unsigned char b = 0xA5; // replace with whatever you've read out of your file
for(i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)
{
    printf("%d", (b>>i)&1); 
}
```

To isolate the most significant bit in a byte:

```
unsigned char mask = 0x80; // this value may differ depending on your system's CHAR_BIT
unsigned char value = /* read from file */;
if(value & mask)
{
   // MSB is set
}
else
{ 
   // MSB is clear
}
```

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < CHAR_BIT; i++)` --> a rare example of _bit endian-ness_.  In this case, little endian.  versus the equally valid big endian with `for(i = CHAR_BIT - 1;  i >= 0; i--)`

Answer (score 3):

As everybody told you there is no bit access functions available in C.

To go more in detail the disk is a **block device** meaning that the access to its contents is allowed only reading and writing chunks of well defined dimensions, that, for historic reasons, are typically 512 bytes large.

So how works functions that allow you to access single `char` at a time (consider that the `char` in C is the smallest data unit, and on some systems it can be different from 8 bits, i.e. 12 or 16 bits)?

The C standard library, and almost all OS file functions, use a buffering mechanism to let you access a single `char`. The system reads a chunk of data from the disk and delivers to you one byte from the chunk, and so on up to the last `char` of the chunk. On the next user request for a `char` the function reads the next file chunk from disk, buffers it internally and supply to the user the very first `char` of the freshly read record data.

This process go on up to reaching the end of the file.

The same process, but in reverse fashion, is executed when **writing** data to the disk a `char` at a time. Each `char` is buffered and when the size of a chunk is reached it is flushed on the physical disk.

To solve your problem you have to write your own set of buffering functions that will read a `char` at time from file and output one bit at time for each request. When the full bitness of the `char` is exausted the function will read another char and starts again.

This is a small sample of such a set of functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/*
 *  Bit FILE pointer structure
 */
typedef struct
{
    FILE *fp;           //Disk file pointer
    int   ReadChar;     //Current char read from stream
    int   BitCounter;   //counter of the current bit
} BITFILE;

/*
 * Function to open a file for bit reading
 */
BITFILE *bfopen(const char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (!fp)    //Error opening file
        return NULL;

    BITFILE *bf = malloc(sizeof(BITFILE));
    if (!bf)    //No memory
    {
        fclose(fp); //Close file
        return NULL;
    }

    bf->fp         = fp;        //Save File pointer
    bf->ReadChar   = getc(fp);  //Read in first char
    bf->BitCounter = 0;         //First bit

    return bf;
}

/*
 * Function to close (release) a bit file
 */
void bfclose(BITFILE *bf)
{
    if (!bf)    //Bad descriptor
        // Do some error signaling
        return;

    fclose(bf->fp); //Close file
    free(bf);       //release memory
}

/*
 * Function to read a single bit
 */
int fgetbit(BITFILE *bf)
{
    if (!bf)    //Bad descriptor
        // Do some error signaling
        return;

    if (bf->BitCounter >= CHAR_BIT)     //No more bits to read on this machine
    {
        bf->ReadChar   = getc(bf->fp);  //Read in another char
        bf->BitCounter = 0;             //Reset counter
    }

    if (EOF == bf->ReadChar)        //If end of file reached return EOF
        return EOF;

    //Note that to avoid sign complications in bit working
    // we cast the value to unsigned
    int bit      = ((unsigned)bf->ReadChar) & 1;    //Get the LSB that we will return
    bf->ReadChar = ((unsigned)bf->ReadChar) >> 1;   //Advance bits shifting

    bf->BitCounter++;   //Update counter

    return bit;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    BITFILE *bf = bfopen("test.txt");
    if (!bf)
    {
        printf("Error can't open file \"%s\"\n", "test.txt");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int cnt=1; ; cnt++)
    {
        int bit = fgetbit(bf);

        if (EOF == bit)
            break;

        printf ("%3d) bit %d\n", cnt, bit);
    }

    bfclose(bf);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just read the file in Binary:

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(input, "rb");
```

and then, you can get individual bits by using something like this:

```
bool getBit(unsigned char byte, int position) // position can be 0-7
{
    return (byte >> position) & 0x1;
}
```